# How to read data in multi level from EF Core Context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, mvvm

I have three classes:

1. **Country**.
2. **District**.
3. **Province**

The classes are:

```
public class Country
{
    public Country()
    {
        Districts = new HashSet<District>();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<District> Districts { get; private set; }
}

public class District
{
    public District()
    {
        Provinces = new HashSet<Province>();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Province> Provinces { get; private set; }
}

public class Province
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

At First, I would like to mention that I am using MVVM with WPF. So, in my ViewModel, I have:

```
Countries = dbContext
              .Countries
              .Include(c => c.Districts)
              .ThenInclude(p => p.Provinces)
              .ToList();
```

Then, in my View, I tried to read **Name** field in **District** and in **Province**. Unfortunately, I couldn't succeed. Just the **Name** field in **Country** is shown.
Then I tried to use debug mode to check **Countries** in my **ViewModel** and I can see the whole data is available.

So, I added this code in my **ViewModel** just to check:

```
string dd = "";
foreach (var country in Countries)
{
    dd += country.Name + "  ";
    dd += country.Districts.Name + "  ";
    dd += country.Districts.Provinces.Name + "  ";
    dd += Environment.NewLine;
}

MessageBox.Show(dd);
```

I can read **country.Name**, but I can't read the rest. Even. I am getting error that they are not found!.

How to read these fields?

Comment: why you have `Ditrict` as the class name? typo?

Comment: @ abdul yes it was.

Comment: The problem is that `country.Districts` and `district.Provinces` are **collections** (i.e. not a single item), so there is no single property `country.Districts.Name` or `country.Districts.Provinces.Name`. Are you trying to present a list with `CountryName, DistrictName, ProvinceName` ? Or better, could you show the desired output?

Comment: @IvanStoev. Thanks for you help. Yes, what I need to accomplish is a list that I can link to a **datagrid** in my WPF form. Btw, I managed to write a code in **ViewModel** with nested **foreach** and I was able to get the whole data. I wish to mark your note as the solution. but how?

Comment: @AbdurahmanAlmatrodi Hey, glad that you solved your issue! And please don't worry (and thanks about your kind proposition), if I wanted to post an answer I would not have posted a comment. But you can post a self answer and I'll be happy to vote it up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Ivan Stone's help. Here is the version that work as I need:

```
string dd = "";
foreach (var country in Countries)
{
    dd += country.Name + "  ";
    foreach (var district in country.Districts)
    {
        dd += district.Name + "  ";

        foreach (var province in district.Provinces)
        {
            dd += province.Name + " ";
        }
    }

    dd += Environment.NewLine;
}

MessageBox.Show(dd);
```